# Indirect Sheet name only as a variable, not workbook or cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Very simple question, I want to recall values from the same cell address from the same workbook from different sheets (tabs) I am returning the values to a different workbook.

I'm using the **`INDIRECT`** method and it works fine, however I do not need the cell address or the workbook name to change and therefore have no need to place it in a variable. Can I concatenate two functions to make the code smaller and faster ?

Below is an extract from my code, which works fine, I am aware that the other workbook needs to be open to return the value.

```
=IF(J65>INDIRECT("'["& $N$1 &"]"& H65 &"'!"& $N$2),INDIRECT("'["& $N$1 &"]"& H65 &"'!"& $N$2),J65)
```

- N1 = Workbookname (Static)
- N2 = Cell Address (Static)
- J65 = Sheetname (variable)

Many thanks.

Comment: You tagged your question `excel-vba` and talk about "code" but you seem to be asking about a  non-vba spreadsheet function. Which is it -- VBA or worksheet function?

Comment: Apologies, it is a worksheet function

Comment: No problem -- I switched the `excel-vba` tag to `excel-formula`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use defined names. I created a workbook called `testbook.xlsx` and then in another workbook I defined two names:

1) Name `target` with value `="!$A$1"`

2) Name `wb` with value `="[testbook.xlsx]"`

It is important that the quotation marks, brackets, explanation marks, etc. are part of the defined name. Note also that `=` is *not* inside the quote marks. For example:

[image]

The you can just use expressions like `INDIRECT(wb & B1 & target)`, which is more readable than what you are doing now:

[image]

For testing purposes I entered the formula `=wb & B1 & target` in C1 to make sure that I defined the strings `wb` and `target` correctly.

5 is indeed the value I put in `A1` in `testbook` and if I change the contents of `B1` in the screenshot above to `Sheet2` the value in C1 successfully changes to the value I have in `[testbook.xlsx]Sheet2!A1`.

Comment: Thanks John, i'll do that.

Comment: Hi John, i did as you suggested, but if i remove the parenthesis, brackets etc, it does not work,  

=INDIRECT("'["&wb&"]"&G62&"'!"&Qb1)

The above does work using the named ranges as suggested, below does not;

=INDIRECT(wb & G64 & Qb1)

Comment: the brackets etc. need to be inside the quote marks in the defined name. See if the edited answer is clearer.